# Jquery Radio Button Detect Changes

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have multiple sets of radio buttons in my page. Each set has two options Type Text or Upload Image. The number of such sets is dynamically determined and are created within the web page using Jquery. Each of these two set of radio buttons is within a form.

My problem is that I am not being able to detect a change in any of these radio buttons. Here is a part of my code that creates the radio buttons -

```
anstypeforms[i] = $('<form style = "padding:5px; margin:5px;">').attr('id',
                    function(){
                        return 'AnsMethod'+quest[k].questionid;
                    }).appendTo($("#AnswerDiv"+quest[i].questionid));
```

where $("#AnswerDiv"+quest[i].questionid is some `<div>` which is created dynamically. quest[i].questionid is a number.

The radio buttons are created as follows -

```
$('<input type="radio" name = "method" value = "TextMethod" checked = "checked" > Type Text </input>').appendTo(anstypeforms[i]);
$('<input type="radio" name = "method" value = "ImageMethod" > Upload Image </input>').appendTo(anstypeforms[i]);
```

Here is the piece of code that tries to detect a change in any of the buttons:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("[id^='AnsMethod']").on('change', 'input[name=method]:radio', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

.......do something......

});
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have an error in your generated HTML. Inputs don't look like `<input> text </input>`.

Answer (score 0):

After several trials got the thing to work using a roundabout way. I first gave an unique name to each of the radio buttons. Then I detected if there is any change in any radio button. Then identified the name of the radio button that was changed. Using the name proceeded with the rest of the code -

```
$('<input type="radio" class="rbutton" value = "TextMethod" checked = "checked" > Type Text </input>').attr('name', function(){
                                            return 'method'+quest[k].questionid;
                                            }).appendTo($("#AnswerDiv"+quest[i].questionid));
$('<input type="radio" class="rbutton" value = "ImageMethod" > Upload Image </input>').attr('name', function(){
                                            return 'method'+quest[k].questionid;
                                            }).appendTo($("#AnswerDiv"+quest[i].questionid));
```

Here is the identifying code -

```
$(document).on("change", 'input[type=radio]', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var x = $(this).attr('name').substring(6);
var y = $(this).attr('value');
switch(y) {
    case 'TextMethod':
        ....do something....
        break;
    case 'ImageMethod':
         ....do something....
        break;
    }
});
```